# I am trying to get the content of a selected item in a combobox by using the following code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
alert($("select[name="+"this.name"+"] option:selected").text());
```

but nothing is being returned unless I give the name of the combobox instead of calling this.name, I might be having problems with the quotes.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can see the complete issue

Comment: this is not a duplicate of given topic. Something must change in stackoverflow. Sometimes experienced developers decides duplicates without reading question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` to get the text of selected option of changed selectbox:

```
$(this).find("option:selected").text();
```

Comment: Oh God that worked thanks very much :)

Comment: Dhara's answer is correct and your code is not working because your adding strings to strings in selector area 

    "select[name="+"this.name"+"] option:selected"

this code vill give you

    "select[name=this.name] option:selected"

as string. But you are trying to add some dynamic content in it so it should be like

    "select[name='"+this.name+"'] option:selected"